# Menu heading unclickable after a while from site load

Tags: javascript, debugging

Here is my problem: In sharepoint menu, headings are unclickable on one of the sites. When i checked site code, it seems that the working sites have href in given menu item, in problematic site they have not. On site load, heading is clickable for a short time, and then href dissapears. My assumption is that some javascript fuction is the problem here. The question is: how can I find it among so many scripts? What should i look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if there are any specific webparts that could contain any scripts.

Add `?Contents=1` (http://example.com?contents=1 or http://example.com/sites/example?contents=1) to the end of your site url to see all the webpart that exists on the page that has the problem. If you find any **Content Editor Web Part** or **Script Editor Web Part**, those could contain the scripts that slows down the page load.

Edit the site if you find any of the webparts mentioned above. If this problem only exists for a single site then it should not be scripts added to the masterpage.

Or you could use the F12 developer tools to see if you can find anything.

Comment: I've checked webparts, it's not it. I'm troubleshooting it in developer tools, trying to find something. The problem exists for all pages in a given site.

Comment: You should be able to use F12 and then select "Network" and then reload the site to see how long all the scripts on the site takes to load.

Comment: Are you using a custom masterpage?

Comment: the problem is not with the long load time, but with the dissapearing href from heading in menu, therefore making it unclickable

Comment: @Wolwgang Did you found it?

Comment: Yes. It took a while, but i found it.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on F12 from chrome or IE and look for errors in console tab. From there you can start troubleshooting!